# Anomalies have similar error values to normal data

Tags: keras, neural-network, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I have inertial measurement unit (IMU) data for which I am building an anomaly detection autoencoder neural net. I have about 5k training samples of which I am using 10% for validation. I also have about 50 (though I can make more) samples to test anomaly detection. My dataset has 12 IMU features. I train for about 10,000 epochs and I attain mean squared errors for reconstruction (MSE) of about 0.004 during training. After training, I perform an MSE calculation on the test data and I get values very similar to those in the train data (0.003) and I do not know why!

I am making my test set by slicing 50 samples from the overall data (not part of X_train) and changing one of the features to all zeros. I have also tried adding noise to one of the features as well as making multiple features zero.

```
np.random.seed(404)
np.random.shuffle(all_imu_data)

norm_imu_data = all_imu_data[:len_slice]
anom_imu_data = all_imu_data[len_slice:]
anom_imu_data[:,6] = 0

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
norm_data = scaler.fit_transform(norm_imu_data)
anom_data = scaler.transform(anom_imu_data)
X_train = pd.DataFrame(norm_data)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(anom_data)
```

I have tried many different network sizes by ranging number of hidden layers and number of hidden nodes/layer. As an example, I show a topology like [12-7-4-7-12]:

```
input_dim = num_features

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))
encoder = Dense(int(7), activation="tanh", activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_layer)
encoder = Dense(int(4), activation="tanh")(encoder)
decoder = Dense(int(7), activation="tanh")(encoder)
decoder = Dense(int(input_dim), activation="tanh")(decoder)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoder)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
history = autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train,
                    epochs=nb_epoch,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_split=0.1,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard]).history
pred_train = autoencoder.predict(X_train)
pred_test = autoencoder.predict(X_test)
mse_train = np.mean(np.power(X_train - pred_train, 2), axis=1)
mse_test = np.mean(np.power(X_test - pred_test, 2), axis=1)
print('MSE mean() - X_train:', np.mean(mse_train))
print('MSE mean() - X_test:', np.mean(mse_test))
```

After doing this, I get MSE mean numbers of 0.004 for Train and 0.003 for Test. Therefore, I cannot select a good threshold for anomalous data, as there are a lot of normal points that have larger MSE scores than the 'anomalous' data.
Any thoughts as to why this network is unable to detect these anomalies?

Comment: Recommend plotting the distribution of anomaly score / reconstruction loss / MSE per instance, grouped by anomaly and not. This will show whether it is possible to choose a threshold to separate the two

Comment: Also, you have a time series with 50 timesteps and 11 features. However your autoencoder is a fully connected type, which has very bad abilities to model time dependencies. I recommend trying a convolutional and/or recurrent autoencoder.

Comment: Have you plotted your 50x12 inputs (as a 2d image)? Is there actually any patterns in there for a network to learn?

Comment: What is the IMU data of, and what kind of anomalies are you looking for?

Comment: @jonnor I've plotted MSE distribution for both in a histogram and there is no point at which I can select a threshold; they normal and anomalous have a very similar distribution.

I am not trying to capture time dependence. I will be testing an LSTM in the near future, but for this phase, a FC AE should still capture patterns.

I havent plotted a 50x12 image, but I do not think I will be able to decipher a pattern. That is what the AE is for! If I could find a pattern, I would just build a classical outlier detector.

This is aircraft IMU. Looking for problems that could cause failures.

Comment: If you as a human (with very skilled visual processing capabilities) cannot see patterns in the data, there is a large risk that your neural network cannot either. There might not even be any patterns!

Comment: What is the time between each timestep from your IMU? Have you tried to only extract vibrations (removing the gravity vector / highpass filtering). Have you tried using STFT to get a spectrogram?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The thing about there maybe being no pattern seems unlikely since I get small recreation errors from the autoencoder, so it is certainly learning some kind of pattern. The issue is that my anomalous data gets recreated well too, so I cant find how to make the separation between the two more pronounced.

Comment: An AE will happily create low reconstruction error for basically any data, no matter how meaningless. It is an universal function estimator after all.

Comment: Then how would it be used to detect anomalies? If I have anomalous data, it should have higher reconstruction error. And with this, I should be able to find a threshold of division. I am not seeing any difference in RE and I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely normal. You train your autoencoder on a sub sample of your whole data. Therefore, there are also anomalies contaminating your training data. The purpose of the autoencoder is to find a perfect reconstruction of your original data which it does including the anomalies. It is a very powerful tool, so if you show it anomalies in the training data, it will reconstruct them easily.

You need to remove 5% of your anomalous data with another anomaly detection algorithm (for example isolation forest) and do the subsampling on that part of the data (without outliers).

After that, you can find your outliers easily.